# Redirects based on date input?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to create a date field.

```
<input id="date" type="date">
```

Based on the user's input, if it is less than 1 week away from today's date, I'd like to redirect to a webpage.

If the input is more than 1 week back from today's date (let's say, today is June 18 and they pick June 10), I'd like to redirect to another page. How do I achieve this?

Comment: by `oninput` event, javascript, simple `if else` statement and `window.location`

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert the date to seconds and compare both dates in the following way:

```
<input id="date" type="date" oninput="redirect()">

<script>
function redirect() {
    var el = document.getElementById("date");
    var interval = Math.abs((new Date(el.value)).getTime() - (new Date()).getTime());
    if (interval > 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000) {
        location.href = url1;
    } else {
        location.href = url2;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Good. Don't forget to replace url1 and url2 with the correct page URLs

Comment: I tried it in a test.html file - when I add the date it doesn't redirect. I've also tried adding the function to an onclick event, like so: <button onclick="redirect()">OK</button>

Comment: I just tried to test it with button on jsFiddle and it redirects correctly in Chrome browser. My test code is here - https://jsfiddle.net/8usk97ch/36/